# Civicrm event calendar doesn't display

Tags: calendar

I have the civicrm events calendar extention installed on three drupal sites. All use drupal 7.69, Civi 7.x-5.22.0, and the event calendar extension 3.2. But on the last site I set up, the calendar does not display. Are there other requirements that I'm missing?

Comment: Is this the osseed extension? I just tried it and it is not displaying for me either. Im using 5.21.0 CiviCRM. You might try installing the date and calendar module in Drupal meantime and make your own calendar.